# Is a family of sets just the subset of a set of sets??

Tags: set-theory

Let A be a set, for $a \in A$, let $X_a$ be a set (so A is a set of sets). A family of sets indexed by A is defined as $$F = \{X_a \mid a \in A \}$$So can we say that F is basically just a subset of a set of sets?. If not, what is wrong with that definition and please provide examples.

Comment: As you say, $F$ is *indexed*.  General sets aren't.

Comment: @lulu Then is it right to say that that F is basically an indexed subset of a set of sets? I may not be grasping the concept of "indexed" fully so could you please explain?

Comment: Say $A=\{1,2\}$.  Then your $F$ consists of two labeled sets  $X_1,X_2$.  If you want $X_1,X_2$ to be subsets of some particular set of sets, that would be an additional requirement.  Beyond that, I'm not sure what you are getting at.  Keep in mind that the collection of all sets is not itself a set.

Comment: I think a family of sets is just a subset of a set of sets. In your case, $F$ is a subset of itself for example. Conversely a subset of a set of sets can be indexed by itself.

Answer (score 2):

The **Axiom Schema of Replacement** of ZFC states:

> If $\mathbf{F}$ is a function, then for any $X$ there exists a set $Y=\mathbf{F}[X]=\{\mathbf{F}(x)\mid x\in X\}$.

More formally, for each formula $\varphi(x,y,p)$, the following is an Axiom of ZFC:
$$\forall x\forall y\forall z\Bigl( \varphi(x,y,p)\wedge \varphi(x,z,p)\to y=z\Bigr) \longrightarrow \forall X\exists Y\forall y\Bigl( y\in Y\leftrightarrow (\exists x\in X)\varphi(x,y,p)\Bigr).$$

A "family" is essentially a set of the form $\mathbf{F}[X]$ for some such function, in which we want to keep track not just of the set $Y$, but also of the set $X$, by "tagging" each element $y\in Y$ with the $x\in X$ such that $\mathbf{F}(x)=y$. Except we write $y_x$ instead of $\mathbf{F}(x)$.

So, essentially, a family of sets is the "range" of a function whose domain is the set $A$ and whose "values" are the sets $A_a$. Or, equivalently, it is the "graph" of the function $\mathbf{F}$,
$$\{ (a,X_a)\mid a\in X\},$$
but we are mostly interested in the $X_a$ rather than in thinking of this as a set of ordered pairs.

Note that every set can be viewed as a family: given a set $X$, we can consider the identity function $i\colon X\to X$, and use it to "index" the set $X$ by indexing each element with itself, $X=\{x_x\mid x\in X\}$.

Comment: Suppose $A = \{1, 2\}$ and $X_1 = X_2 = B$. Is the family equal to $\{B\}$? I think there is a problem with this because one says 'the product of the family' for example to mean $B\times B$, but this notion of product depends on $A$ as well. Or perhaps the expression 'product of the family' is incorrect?

Comment: @Gribouillis I've added some words to clarify. Essentially, the family is the "graph" of the function $\mathbf{F}$, but we are mostly interested in thinking about the range rather than think of it as the set of ordered pairs. Viewed that way, with the family written as $\{(a,X_a)\mid a\in A\}$, the "product of the family" is $\prod_{a\in  A} X_a$ and there are no issues.

Comment: Thinking again, the "product of the family" is still ambiguous because $X_1\times X_2$ is not equal to $X_2\times X_1$.

Comment: @Gribouillis They are naturally isomorphic, and categorically (considering the projections), they are isomorphic up to unique isomorphism, so it doesn't matter.